# Indicar formulário qual método da classe utilizar

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, mvc, formulário, objetos

Tenho um form que vai exibir os campos a serem inseridos no bd, até ai tudo bem, o problema se encontra no seguinte:

Eu criei uma classe (esse arquivo irá receber várias solicitações distintas) com os métodos `add`, `edit`, `delete`, `find`, etc. eu preciso que ao enviar o meu formulário no arquivo que vai receber a solicitação ele descubra qual a solicitação que eu estou enviando (`add`, `edit`, `delete`, etc.) e encaminhe para o método certo para tratar a funcionalidade, alguém sabe como posso dizer ao formulário para executar um determinado método da minha classe?

---

### Edit  - Adicionado código

arquivo: ServicosController.php

```
class ServicosController extends AppController {

public function add() {
    $servico = $_POST['servico'];

    if (!$servico) {
        echo 'Serviço inválido.';           
    } else {
        $database->insert('servicos', [
            'title' => $servico['title'],
            'value' => $servico['value']
            ]);
    }
}
```

}

já o formulário de envio não tem nenhuma particularidade por enquanto mesmo.. são só 2 inputs msm...

Comment: Coloca ai o código.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o [Symfony Form Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/introduction.html) para executar essa tarefa. Com esse componente, é possível usar um objeto para renderizar um formulário; assim como é possível mapear os valores submetidos por meio de um formulário, em um objeto.

Veja um exemplo que eles mesmo fornecem:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

$form = $formFactory->createBuilder()
    ->add('task', 'text')
    ->add('dueDate', 'date')
    ->getForm();

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    $data = $form->getData();

    // ... perform some action, such as saving the data to the database

    $response = new RedirectResponse('/task/success');
    $response->prepare($request);

    return $response->send();
}
```